# I am getting an type error saying that the urllib.response has no attribute 'META' and am getting pointed towards my csrf.py file

Tags: django, django-csrf

This is the error I get when trying to go past the login page I have set up.

```
module 'urllib.response' has no attribute 'META'
```

What do I need to delete from the csrf.py file to fix this?

Also, the function that is not working right in csrf.py is the get_token function on line 84.

Here's that CSRF function for reference:

```
def get_token(request):
    if "CSRF_COOKIE" not in request.META:
        csrf_secret = _get_new_csrf_string()
        request.META["CSRF_COOKIE"] = _mask_cipher_secret(csrf_secret)
    else:
        csrf_secret = _unmask_cipher_token(request.META["CSRF_COOKIE"])
    request.META["CSRF_COOKIE_USED"] = True
    return _mask_cipher_secret(csrf_secret)
```

Environment:

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/register/

Django Version: 3.2.2
Python Version: 3.9.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'mainpage',
 'register.apps.RegisterConfig']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']


Template error:
In template C:\Users\david\OneDrive\Desktop\Django\Tango\register\templates\register\userinfo.html, error at line 43
   module 'urllib.response' has no attribute 'META'
   33 : }
   34 : &lt;/style&gt;
   35 : &lt;body&gt;
   36 : 
   37 : &lt;h3&gt;Now For Some Basic Info&lt;/h3&gt;
   38 : 
   39 : &lt;div&gt;
   40 :   {% block content %}
   41 :   &lt;form action="" method="post"&gt;
   42 :     &lt;label for="fname"&gt;First Name&lt;/label&gt;
   43 :      {% csrf_token %} 
   44 :     &lt;input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your first name.."&gt;
   45 :     &lt;label for="lname"&gt;Last Name&lt;/label&gt;
   46 :     &lt;input type="text" id="lname" name="lastname" placeholder="Your last name.."&gt;
   47 : 
   48 :     &lt;label for="DOB"&gt;Date Of Birth&lt;/label&gt;
   49 :     &lt;input type="text" id="DOB" name="DOB" placeholder="The Date you were born"&gt;
   50 : 
   51 :     &lt;label for="Email"&gt;Email Address&lt;/label&gt;
   52 :     &lt;input type="text" id="Email" name="Email" placeholder="Your email address"&gt;
   53 : 


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\david\OneDrive\Desktop\Django\Tango\Tango\views.py", line 22, in register
    return render(response,"register/userinfo.html")
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\shortcuts.py", line 19, in render
    content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader.py", line 62, in render_to_string
    return template.render(context, request)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\backends\django.py", line 61, in render
    return self.template.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 170, in render
    return self._render(context)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 162, in _render
    return self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\loader_tags.py", line 53, in render
    result = self.nodelist.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 938, in render
    bit = node.render_annotated(context)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\base.py", line 905, in render_annotated
    return self.render(context)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\defaulttags.py", line 55, in render
    if csrf_token:
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 246, in inner
    self._setup()
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 382, in _setup
    self._wrapped = self._setupfunc()
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\template\context_processors.py", line 23, in _get_val
    token = get_token(request)
  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\middleware\csrf.py", line 84, in get_token
    if "CSRF_COOKIE" in request.META:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /register/
Exception Value: module 'urllib.response' has no attribute 'META'
```

view.py file(Login Function)

```
class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    fname = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    lname = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
    dob = forms.datefield()
    email = forms.EmailField()



class CommentForm(forms.Form):
fname = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
lname = forms.CharField(max_length=25)
dob = forms.datefield()
email = forms.EmailField()

if request.method== "POST":
    form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        cd = form.cleaned_data
        Info = form(
            name = cd['name'],
            dob = cd['dob'],
            pytype = cd['ptype'],
            hobby1 = cd['hobby1'],
            hobby2 = cd['hobby2'],
            hobby3 = cd['hobby3'], 
    )
    form.save()
```

Comment: The title says that the error is "module is not iterable", but the question says that the error is "no attribute META".  Which is it?

Comment: Right now, it is No attribute META. But when I tried playing around with the CSRF file I got another error of "module not iterable", probably cuz I played with it too much.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), do you see that option of "Switch to copy and paste view"? Click that and copy paste the error in your post.

Comment: The problem is probably from the line `return render(response,"register/userinfo.html")` (from the error) in your view. What is `response`? The first argument you pass to the `render` function is supposed to be the request object.

Comment: Ah, tried replacing response with request and everything is working now, originally, I had the login logic in my main view file, but moved it all to a separate app and forgot to revise it to just link to that view. Thank you for your help!